# Ignore directories in brunch production build

Tags: brunch

How can I exclude my test directory from my production build?

I've looked through the documentation, and can't seem to find any option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`overrides`](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#overrides) config option to override `files` in production or other environment.

Comment: that still copies assets from the test directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: You will also need to override `paths.watched` - set it to `['app', 'vendor']`.